# How to get TFS uri in (tfs) build script?

Tags: build, tfs

I have custom component (in tfs build workflow script) that requires tfs access (and for that reason requires tfs project uri, eg. https://tfsstuf.insomewhere.fi:8080/tfs/). Is that uri available in any of tfs build workflow properties? I have tried look through BuildAgent properties etc. but no luck so far.

Another possible solution is that there is project collection object available somewhere, because custom component creates it from that uri.

Reason for this is that i don't want hardcode that uri deep inside of build script, because it may change.

Comment: Are you after the URL for the Team Foundation Service, or the URI for a Build? Are you using the TFS API to get this, or just get it from Visual Studio and e-mail it to someone?

Comment: Sorry, wrote it badly first time. This issue is with tfs build workflow scripts and in one of my custom component (activity) in it. Edited question, hopefully more clear now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how:

```
 BuildDetail.BuildServer.TeamProjectCollection.Uri.AbsoluteUri
```

Read more here:  [TFS 2010 TfsUrl location](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/tfsbuild/thread/3d094a1a-7c3e-40de-9405-2f7d61f6e062)