# Get path to Build summary wep page in Build process template

Tags: tfs, build-automation

Im using Windows workflow build process template to create my build script. In my build script I would like the url to the Build summary page that is accessable from the TFS Web.
The url is for example:
http://host.com:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/MyProject/_build#buildUri=vstfs%3A%2F%2F%2FBuild%2FBuild%2F173&logPath=&_a=summary.
In what variables/arguments in the workflow can I find this url?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also asked the question in the msdn forums and got the answer:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3ecb7a3b-1b5c-4cfa-95a9-70a2563a5810/get-path-to-build-summary-wep-page-in-build-process-template

Answer (score 2):

The URL seems to have some fixed things and some variables such as the build URI, log path etc. You can try to make the URL using these parts -

The following might help you get the build URI - [How to get TFS uri in (tfs) build script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14640983/how-to-get-tfs-uri-in-tfs-build-script)